# How NLP can be used to map a customer's response to some pre-defined action?

Tags: nlp

We want to map a customer's response to one of our actionable tasks.

Example 1 -
Customer: When will my vehicle be picked up?
System: Customer is asking for pickup date, so provide one.

Example 2 -
Customer: I don’t have title.
System: Customer has title issue. Create a task for support team to help him.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at some APIs that will translate statements like that into intents. A great one I've worked with before is Nuance's mix.nlu which can be found here:

> https://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=mix